OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#logo"}
I have been given an exception for the case where I am trying to locate a company logo using elinium
Message:
Test method Seleniumtesting.UnitTest1.VerifyLogo threw exception:
OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#logo"}
(Session info: chrome=125.0.6422.142); For documentation on this error, please visit:     https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
Stack Trace: 
WebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse, String commandToExecute)
WebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
WebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism, String value)
<.ctor>b__11_0(ISearchContext context)
By.FindElement(ISearchContext context)
WebDriver.FindElement(By by)
UnitTest1.VerifyLogo() line 36

I suspect some of the web elements, like a text box, are what need to be initialized, but I don't think that logo is the right selector. I still seem lost
Using explicit waits still left me in the same pit hole. I still seem lost.
